# UICollectionViewCell signal to UICollectionView didSelect

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

On top of my `UICollectionViewCell`s in my `UICollectionView` I've overlaid a `UIButton` that intercepts touches so I can respond to touch events more granularly. The issue is that now the collection view no longer gets `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` messages. (For obvious reasons... the button has absorbed the touch and isn't signaling to the collection view that the item was selected.)

Is there a way to signal to the collection view that the cell was selected? I've seen similar questions but none seem to give a convincing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `pointInside:withEvent:` message on UIView [and subclasses] and return `false` to continue propagating the touch event.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:

```
class PassThroughButton: UIButton {
  override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    // do something
    // then continue event propigation
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution—not only because it solved my problem but I learned how to propagate touches. Thank you!